# Insert array posts in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have to insert the data into the table as follows:
In one request, there are a number of people which will be included in the request.
Now, I am done with inserting the request information.
I am getting a problem in inserting the people's information together with the request id into the request_details table.

For Example:

In request table:

```
Request table
Request ID  |  Description
1           |  sample1


Request Details
Req_det_id    |   Request ID  |  Person    |Quantity
1             |     1         |  P1        | 10
2             |     1         |  P2        |20
```

How would I able to achieve inserting the arrays into the request details table?

In my view:

```
<div id="show" style="display:none;">
    <select name="hhname[]" value="" id="drop2"  style="color:black;">
            <?php
                foreach ($head as $row) {
                    echo "<option style='color:black;' value='".$row['hh_id']."'>".$row['hh_fname']."  ".$row['hh_lname']."</option>";
                                            }
                          ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="quant[]" value="">
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
$req_data = array(
            'requestor_id' => $input['requestor_id'],
            'request_package_id' => $r_id,
            'request_place' => $input['request_place'],
            'request_date' => $input['request_date'],
            'request_remarks' => $input['request_remarks'],
            'request_specify' => $input['request_specify'],
            'request_quantity' => $input['request_quantity'],
            'request_status' => 1,
            'request_code' => "fsdf2324",

        );
        $request_id = $this->CreateRequest_model->addReq($req_data);
        $this->CreateRequest_model->updatePackTable($input['package_id']);

        $name = $input['hhname']; // this is already an array
        $quant = $input['quant']; // this is an array

        foreach ($name as $row ) {
            $data = array(
                //how should i insert it to the req details table?
            );
        }
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new associative array and push that associative array in a different array and use this->db->insert_batch('table_name', batch_Array to be inserted).

eg.
Controller:

```
$name = $input['hhname']; // this is already an array
$quant = $input['quant']; // this is an array
$cnt = count($name);
$cnt1 = count($quant);
 $push_arr = array();
for($i=0; $i<$cnt && $i<$cnt1; $i++)
{
  $tmp_arr = array('$request_id' => $request_id,
                   'Person'=> $name[$i],
                   'Quantity'=>$quant[$i]);
 array_push($push_arr,$tmp_arr);
}
$this->Your_model->insert_request_details($push_arr);
```

Model:

```
function insert_request_details($push_arr)
{
   $val = $this->db->insert_batch('Request Details',$push_arr);
   return val;
}
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thank you so much, you saved my day bro.